# JTable.clearSelection() vs Jtable.getSelectionModel.clearSelection() - When to use what?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, selection, selectionmodel

I need to cancel all selections within a JTable model object. Java provides this function "clearSelection()" which does, what I need, as far as I understand.

But I am confused why this function can be called on a JTable object as well as on a selection model for a JTable object:

```
 1) mytable.clearSelection();
 2) mytable.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
```

Both ways work, but I do not understand in what situation a clearSelection() of a SelectionModel (like at 2) ) would make any sense. As far as I understood SelectionModels, they are used to decide what kind of selections a JTable allows. I use the SelectionModel to only allow a Selection of exactly one row

```
//allow only one row to be selected
mytable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
```

Which way is to be preferred in what kind of situation? Is there a good reason not to use way 1?

I would be glad if anyone has some beginner friendly explanation for that. Thx in advance.

Comment: Maybe it uses the default model when you call table.clearSelection(), but that' s just a guess!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the implementation of `JTable#clearSelection()`

```
public void clearSelection() {
    selectionModel.clearSelection();
    columnModel.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
}
```

As you can see, there is two `ListSelectionModel` which are cleared, because you can select column and/or row and/or cell.

From Oracle tutorial :

> JTable uses a very simple concept of selection, managed as an
>   intersection of rows and columns. It was not designed to handle fully
>   independent cell selections.

A `ListSelectionModel` handle all aspect of the selection such as which row is selected, how can we select some rows, etc... Not only the kind of selection !
More information in [the Oracle JTable tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection)

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanations. So If I got you right, selectionModel.clearSelection() clears the selection of rows and columnModel.getSelectionModel().clearSelection() clears the selection of columns, so that both together will clear a selection on a cell, correct?
Since your explenation I got the feeling that calling mytable.clearSelection() is to be prefered to mytable.getSelectionModel().clearSelection(), since it does a more extensive clearing.
Thank you for the hint about the ListSelectionModel.

Comment: @Simeon It should be something like that, except I think only clear the selection of columns (or row) is enough to deselect a cell. (if there is no row selected, how a cell can be selected. Same reasoning with column). Glad to be helpful ;)

Answer (score 5):

Usually when you see two methods like that it is because the table will invoke the SelectionModel.clearSelection() method for you. So the table method is a convenience method.

In this case the actual code is:

```
public void clearSelection() 
{
    selectionModel.clearSelection();
    columnModel.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
}
```

So both the row and column selection models are cleared.